# Read about Name Node and Checkpoint node. Can't clealy understand what are the contents of FSImage file and Edits log files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I understand that Name node doesn't keep the block locations of files in FSImage. It keeps all that information in RAM.

So what does FSImage file and edits log files have?

thanks
basam

Answer (score 0):

**FSImage** is a snapshot of what is the actual metadata of a cluster at some point of time, and a copy this snapshot will be in RAM and if you made any changes to the metadata of cluster like, created  or deleted one file in hdfs. This is changed metadata is captured by **editlogs**. **Editlogs** and **FSImage** are merged periodically to have always the latest information about metadata in FSImage. So when restart your cluster due to any reason , Namenode machine does all the transactions from the EditLog to the in-memory representation of the FsImage.

Comment: Syadav, Thanks for the response. Could you give me sample data in FSIImage and Editslogs file?  Thanks much. Kind regards

Comment: check this out:- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html

Comment: Thanks folks. Kind regards

Comment: wc :- ) please add favour by upvoting anwser. If you really think it was useful.

Comment: I tried clicking on "Up" arrow. It says I don't have enough reputations to vote